# Google Script - To add in coding for the value to go to the section based on the answer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following script, so that it can help me to update a few list based on the title.

```
var ssID = "SHEET LINK";
var formID = "FORM LINK";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Data");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){


var labels = wsData.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  labels.forEach(function(label,i){

    var options = wsData
                  .getRange(2, i+1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1)
                  .getValues()
                  .map(function(o){ return o[0] })
                  .filter(function(o){ return o !== "" });

    updateDropdownUsingTitle(label,options);

  });
  }  


function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });


  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();

  updateDropdown(itemID,values); 
}


function updateDropdown(id,values) {

  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

Is there a script that I can add in so that if they we to select 'A' it will go to section 3 but the rest they will go to section 2 without overwriting the above? I do not want to add in sections in the script as I already set it up in my original form. I tried a few codes but was not able to get it right. FYI, I am not very good at scripts.

Comment: So you'd like to modify the form while the user is editing?

Comment: sorry if my explanation was not clear. Not to modify the form while the user is editing but when I update the list in my form using the script above, my setting for 'Go to section based on answer' will be removed. I want to incorporate a script to what I have so that my 'Go to section based on answer' can remain when I update the listing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to follow the question and I didn't get a notification. Could you add a spreadsheet with mock data (this is public, be careful with private information) so I can understand the structure better?